# RDP Logging into Wrong Server

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2019

I'm in the process of setting up our new server and can connect to it while on the same network. The issue is when remote employees try to log in it takes them to our old server running 2008r2 instead of our new server running 2019. During tests I use credentials for the new server yet it somehow still logs me into the old server. When I turn off the old server and use the same new server credentials I get the normal "Remote Desktop can't connect to the remote computer for one these three reasons: 1. Remote access to the server is not enabled 2. Remote computer is off 3. Remote computer is not available on the network (Which it should be as I can connect to it when on the same network)."

Requiring Network Level Authentication is turned off so I'm not sure what else to try. It makes no sense that credentials for the new server would log me into our old server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When people login remotely, they login using the public ip address, rather than the private ip address. This means the traffic goes through a router.

Given that you end up at the old server means there is a port forwarding rule on a router that points to the wrong private ip address. Access the router responsible for the port forwardings, or contact those who manage the router and get the ipaddress altered to the correct one.

Comment: THANK YOU! I never would have thought about that. Changed the router settings just now and it worked. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Glad I could help.